# Cocoa touch NSInteger plusing 4 not 1

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, math, nsinteger

I have this cocoa touch code where you press a button and a NSInteger adds its self with the number 1 and then a label turnes into the NSInteger value

This is the code

```
- (IBAction)out:(id)sender {

outnum = outnum + 1;

self.outnumberlabel.text =  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%d", outnum];
```

Everything works, but the NsInteger is adding 4 when it is ment to add 1

And when I put in

```
outnum = outnum + 2;
```

The label turns to 8

It is going up in fours does anybody know why and how to fix it

Comment: what is the initial value of `out`?

Comment: The initial value of out is 0

Comment: r u sure, this action is called once?

Comment: Yes I just check there with an Nslog

Comment: unusual, try changing the method name to someother than `out`

Comment: Did that it still added 4 not 1

Answer (score 1):

Check your outnum declaration - you'll see this behaviour if you declare

```
NSInteger *outnum;
```

rather than

```
NSInteger outnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `out:` method is being called four times more often than you expect. Try putting an `NSLog` line in this code to confirm. If that's the case, you'll need to figure out why the method is being called so much.

Comment: No it is not that. I forgot to mention when I put in out = out + 2; It gives me eight not four as if it is going up in the four times tables.

Comment: No it is not that because I put in an NSLog and the NSLog only activated once

Comment: Do you know is it possible to add 0.25 to the NSInteger.

Comment: It's not possible to add fractional values to an `NSInteger`. I would suggest changing the variable `out` to be named something else instead.